# menubar not defined in python

Tags: python, tkinter

i am trying to make a program using the tkinter library in python but it gives error showing that ---

NameError: name 'menubar' is not defined

```
import tkinter
import sys


def hey():
    print("hello")


def myNew():
    mlabel = Label(root,text="yo").pack()



root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Wizelane")

root.geometry('400x80+350+340')
filemenu = tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New",command=myNew)

label = tkinter.Label(root,text="say hello")
label.pack()
hello = tkinter.Button(root,text="hello",command=hey)
hello.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: check here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_menu.htm

Comment: add root.config(menu=menubar)  line before root.mainloop(). May be it work

Comment: What do you expect to happen here? You have to define the variable `menubar` before using it.

Comment: what do you think `Menu(menubar, ...)` is doing? Why did you put `menubar` in that statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some important parts here.

You need to configure the menu first and you also need to add the cascade label.

Take a look at this code.

```
import tkinter

def hey():
    print("hello")

def myNew():
    # you forgot to use tkinter.Label here.
    mlabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="yo").pack()


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Wizelane")
root.geometry('400x80+350+340')

my_menu = tkinter.Menu(root)

# configure root to use my_menu widget.
root.config(menu = my_menu) 

# create a menu widget to place on the menubar
file_menu = tkinter.Menu(my_menu, tearoff=0)

# add the File cascade option for drop down use
my_menu.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = file_menu)

# then add the command you want to add as a File option.
file_menu.add_command(label="New", command = myNew)

label = tkinter.Label(root, text="say hello")
label.pack()

hello = tkinter.Button(root, text="hello", command = hey)
hello.pack()

root.mainloop()
```